# Is set difference commutative and associative?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

> Given question:

The **[set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory))** of two sets $A$ and $B$ is $A \setminus B = \{x \in A \;|\; x \not\in B \}.$

Recall that we would say that set difference is commutative if $A \setminus B = B \setminus A$ for all sets $A$ and $B$, and we would say that set difference is associative if $A \setminus (B \setminus C) = (A \setminus B) \setminus C$ for all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Which of the following is true?

(a) Set difference is neither commutative nor associative.

(b) Set difference is commutative but not associative.

(c) Set difference is associative but not commutative.

(d) Set difference is both commutative and associative.

> My actual problem: I understand the commutative and associative properties of sets, but I don't really understand the first sentence of the question.

Can someone please explain this question to me? And can someone guide me through this question? Thank you!

Comment: What don't you understand? Is $A\setminus B$ always equal to B\setminus A $ (is it ever?). If it's always true setminus is commutative.  If it is not always true, setminus is not commutative.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference concept.

Comment: If A = {a,b,c,d,e} and B ={c,d,e,f,g}. $A\setminus B $={a,b}. $B\setminus A $={f,g}

Comment: $A \setminus B = A \cap B^c $.  It's just what the definition says it is: it's all the elements in A that at not in set B.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for clarifying! Can you make your response an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $A=\{1\}$, $B=\emptyset$ for commutativity; $A=B=C\ne\emptyset$ for associativity.

Answer (score 1):

The associativity might be understood with a geometrical counter example. Consider $A$ as the disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of finite radius, $B$ the infinite line at $45$ degrees and $C$ the $x$-axis.

$B-C$ is $B-\lbrace 0\rbrace$. $A-(B-C) = (A-B)\cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ (the disk $A$ without its diagonal but with the element zero).

$A-B$ is the disk without its diagonal, and $(A-B)-C$ is the disk without its diagonal and the intersection with the $x$ axis.

Thus $A-(B-C)\neq (A-B)-C$.

It will hold only for a certain case described [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_Difference_is_not_Associative).